# Apache won't server static assets for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to configure my apache server for serving static assets from my rails app. I already tried the suggested configurations but my assets still aren't shown and when trying to access them directly I just got an rails error that no matching controller was found but the asset stuff should be handled by apache directly I think.
My apache configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxx
DocumentRoot /home/xxx/test/public
PassengerEnabled off

<LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</LocationMatch>
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9292/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9292/
</VirtualHost>
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: Assets, as in .css? Have you done a rake to the public/assets folder?

Comment: yeah i compiled my assets and they are all in place

Answer (score 0):

I used,

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

To make it all work right, I added this to config/application.rb...

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
.
.
    config.assets.precompile += ['custom.css']    
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
.
.
  end
end
```

(I had created custom.css.scss. But Rails did not recognize .scss, as you see above.) I assume that all your assets are appearing in public/assets folder after precompile. I don't understand what you are doing with LocationMatch, pardon my ignorance. Further more, I did not use port 80. I used 8000. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Also, there's a setting in config/environments/production.rb,

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: sorry but this does not really fit my question. I've done all the steps you mention but if I understood it right rails should NOT be involved when serving the assets. Apache should do this on its own. And therefor is the `LocationMatch`. But rails is still handling requests to the assets directory which should be done by apache directly

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from the Rails Asset-pipeline documentation regarding the Apache server:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

**4.1.1 Far-future Expires Header**

Precompiled assets exist on the file system and are served directly by your web server. They do not have far-future headers by default, so to get the benefit of fingerprinting you'll have to update your server configuration to add those headers.

For Apache:

```
# The Expires* directives requires the Apache module
# `mod_expires` to be enabled.
<Location /assets/>
  # Use of ETag is discouraged when Last-Modified is present
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
  # RFC says only cache for 1 year
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</Location>
```